# Can i create the custom URL for the product category in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there any way to create the custom URL only for the product category.using the function.php file
like:- http://example.com/taxonomy/parentCategory/subCategory/

Answer (score 1):

Changing URL is not easy task, I would recommend to do it with plugin.
For example with this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-permalink-manager/

Comment: Hi  @ivan-frolov this functionality is premium. can you suggest the free plugin. or anyway i can do using the function.php

Comment: it's [freemium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium#:~:text=Freemium%2C%20a%20portmanteau%20of%20the,the%20free%20version%20of%20the)
There are only two features (redirects and 'ability to remove the base from the product tags URL') available in premium only, all other features are free.